# How to install fzf.vim with Vundle?

Tags: plugin-vundle, plugin-vim-plug

I use Vundle to manage my vim plugins. However I just came across [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim), and its installation instructions require that I use vim-plug.

How do I make this happen? Wouldn't there be a conflict between vundle and vim-plug?

## update

I tried installing it using vundle by putting the following in my `~/.vimrc`

```
call vundle#begin()
..
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf.vim'        
call vundle#end()            " required
```

this seems to have worked fine.. but then when I run vim and type `Files` I get this error in vim:

```
Error detected while processing function fzf#vim#files[15]..<SNR>47_fzf[18]..<SNR>47_wrap:
line   12:
E117: Unknown function: fzf#wrap
E15: Invalid expression: fzf#wrap(a:name, opts, a:bang)
line   14:
E121: Undefined variable: wrapped
E15: Invalid expression: wrapped
Error detected while processing function fzf#vim#files[15]..<SNR>47_fzf:
line   18:
E117: Unknown function: fzf#run
E15: Invalid expression: fzf#run(s:wrap(a:name, merged, bang))
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

what do I do?

## update 2

I installed fzf using brew:

```
$ which fzf
/usr/local/bin/fzf
```

but same bug appears..

back to the original question: can vundle and vim-plug co-exist?

Comment: It's weird that it doesn't work, maybe you can also try to ask directly to junegunn via [the issue tracker](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues). I'll delete our previous comments which will not be usefull to other readers.

Comment: for reference, here is the question: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/457

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've installed the **fzf.vim** wrapper plugin, but you haven't installed the base **fzf** plugin, which provides the underlying functionality, including the autoload functions that the error messages are flagging as "Unknown".

Try using:

```
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf'
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
```

Comment: works.. quick question: what does it mean when a repo on git hub ends in `.vim` rather than the rest of them (ie `.git`)? Does it have a special meaning?

Comment: @abbood It usually indicates that the repository is a Vim plugin, but it's just the name that the repository creator picked, so it doesn't really *mean* anything in the way you're imagining.